# Necessary to call toHaveBeenCalledTimes

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a assertion with

`toHaveBeenCalledWith`

Do you think it's necessary to assert also the

`toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`toHaveBeenCalledWith(arg1)` verifies that there has been at ***LEAST one*** call with the passed in arguments.

**calls > 0 && arg === arg1**

`toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` verifies that is has ***only*** been called ***once*** with any arguments.

**calls === 1**

Therefore `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` is not nessesary unless you want to make sure that it has only been called a very specific number of times.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you have any API call which is getting called inside a function for more than 1 times, then it is better to Assert like this: `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)` (3 times called).

Else if it just a one call then you can have a check as `toHaveBeenCalled()`. It should get your code covered.

Comment: Do you think the `toHaveBeenCalledWIth()` also checks that it has been called 1 time? Or is it necessary to assert both in one test?

`toHaveBeenCalledWith` and `toHaveBeenCalledWith`

Comment: If you are using `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`, then there is no need to use `toHaveBeenCalled()` again. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: It's `toHaveBeenCalledWith` with `toHaveBeenCalled()` vs. calling `toHaveBeenCalledWith` only.

Comment: `toHaveBeenCalledWith(arg1, arg2, ...)` takes multiple arguments as `arg1`, `arg2` etc. It is used when your function has some arguments (at least 1) and `toHaveBeenCalled()` takes no argument. It is used when your function doesn't use any arguments.